# Convert sObject Time datatype to Time datatype

Tags: apex, javascript, sobject

I want to convert a *sObject query response parameter* to a Time object which will be displayed in the front-end, and I am a bit confused since there is no method **valueof()** in the class **Time** in Apex like there is in the class **Date**.

I have used the below method to wrap a sObject to a Visit object.

```
public static List<Visit> getVisits(List<SObject> objs) {
    List<Visit> visits = new List<Visit>();
    for (SObject obj : objs) {
      Visit visit = new Visit();
        visit.visitDate=Date.valueOf(obj.get('Date__c'));
        Visit.visitTime= (Time)obj.get('Time__c');
        visit.patientEmail= String.valueOf(obj.get('Patient_Email__c'));
        visit.patientName=String.valueOf(obj.get('Patient_Name__c'));
        visit.visitDescription=String.valueOf(obj.get('Description__c'));
        visit.visitName=String.valueOf(obj.get('Name'));
      visits.add(visit);
    }

    return visits;
}
```

---

```
class Visit{
    @AuraEnabled
    public Date visitDate;

    @AuraEnabled
    public Time visitTime;

    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String patientEmail;
    
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String patientName;

    @AuraEnabled
    public String visitDescription;

    @AuraEnabled
    public String visitName;
}
```

But unfortunately the **Visit.visitTime= (Time)obj.get('Time__c');** line just converts it into gibberish number string in this format: *900000*
Maybe there is some provided method that does this conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Time data type in Javascript, so you're getting the number of milliseconds (a timestamp).
[Formatted Time](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-time/documentation) component requires an ISO8601 formatted time string, so you could change the type of `visitTime` to `String` and then store it as
`Visit.visitTime = String.valueOf((Time)obj.get('Time__c'));`.
This way you'll get an ISO8601 time string, like `10:40:57.000Z`.

Otherwise, if you cannot change the type of `visitTime`, you could use a [Formatted Date Time](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-date-time/documentation) component.
This component accepts a timestamp as value and if you want to display only the time, you have to set the following attributes: `hour`, `minute` and `second`.
I.E.

```
<lightning-formatted-date-time
    value="900000"
    hour="2-digit"
    minute="2-digit"
    second="2-digit">
</lightning-formatted-date-time>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!